# Memory corruption while setting value inside GMock Wrap function

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a requirement wherein I need to mock a non-virtual function using GTest/GMock. So, I have wrapped that function and linked the same in the test suite "tst_def" file. For the wrapped function, an integer is passed by reference and when I set any value inside the wrapped function to this integer, the test suite "Crashes with memory corruption" during execution (Segmentation fault).

Important observation:
 This crash doesn't occur when I set the same default value for that integer inside wrapped function as its assigned during its creation but crashes only when i assign any other value.

*Edit*:

Consider, value1 passed to this wrapper function has initial value of 0.

```
extern "C" {
int __wrap_function(int &value1)
{
    value1 = 3; //crashes
    value1 = 0; //didnt crash
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Consider, value1 passed to this wrapper function has initial value of 0.

extern "C"
{
 int __wrap_function(int &value1)
 {
  value1 = 3; //crashes
  value1 = 0; //didnt crash
 
  return 0;
 }
}

Comment: I added the wrapper code to your question. Please verify, if it's correct. You can do this yourself. Just use the small edit link below your question.